# Iterate python list and capitalize specific letters

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python, which I'd like to iterate and capitalize every letter that isn't 'A', so turn this list:

```
['albert', 'angela', 'leo', 'bridget']
```

Into:

```
['aLBERT', 'aNGELa', 'LEO', 'BRIDGET']
```

Comment: I'd suggest you look at Duncan's answer as I believe it would be much better on a large list. In fact, just on your list, his answer is almost 6x faster, as tested w/ the timeit module

Comment: @jwesonga: Can you specify what to do with letters 'a' and 'A'?  In fact, some answers transform 'Alberta' into 'ALBERTA' while some others transform it into 'aLBERTA'.

Comment: also can you say what you want to do with accented letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the existing answers seem to want to operate on the characters individually. It is simpler and easier just to handle the words as a whole:

```
>>> the_list = ['albert', 'angela', 'leo', 'bridget']
>>> [ word.upper().replace('A', 'a') for word in the_list]
['aLBERT', 'aNGELa', 'LEO', 'BRIDGET']
```

Comment: was just about to post this.  I think it's better than the other answer because it has way less calls and no if conditions

Comment: Unless you've got `Albert` and you want it to become `ALBERT` not `aLBERT`. But it's not clear from the example whether uppercase letters are allowed to start with. (And my answer doesn't operate on the characters individually, and even uses less function calls than this one, @pyInTheSky, n+3 rather than n*2, though it doesn't work for non-ASCII characters.)

Comment: very nice, i've used it before but didn't know it was that fast

Answer (score 4):

```
[''.join(c.upper() if c != 'a' else c for c in word) for word in the_list]
```

Comment: @EOL: I'd argue that a solution using the `map` function could be simpler, though not by much..

Comment: @machineyearning A lightning strikes a little kitten every time someone says map is better than a comprehension... Just saying

Comment: @EOL:  Simpler would be `[word.upper().replace('A','a') for word in the_list]`.  This works as it's ok to convert 'Adam' to 'aDaM'.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski And to win the code golf challenge I would go further: `eval(str(the_list).upper().replace('A','a'))` :D

Comment: @JBernardo:  I see your smiley face.  But I want to emphasize my emphasis was on simpler, not shorter.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I know, but not sure if turning "Adam" into "aDaM" is ok or not...

Comment: @Jbernardo: Not sure I understand what you're getting at. Please explain why you don't like using `map` in the place of a comprehension. It seems to me like they do the same thing, but `map` is just a standard higher-level abstraction that is often used for list processing.

Comment: @machineyearning In most cases, map is plain ugly and had it's behaviour changed from Python 2 to 3. Also, comprehensions don't require lambda functions or any function call at all...

Comment: @JBernardo: I see your point, thanks for explaining. This thread helped me see your point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> sl = ['albert', 'angela', 'leo', 'bridget']
>>> [re.sub('[^a]+', lambda m: m.group(0).upper(), s) for s in sl]
['aLBERT', 'aNGELa', 'LEO', 'BRIDGET']
```

Comment: Maybe it wasn't @EOL. Regex — it depends. On strings of thouzands characters, regex will be few times faster than JBernardo's solution (you can check that with `timeit`). They are also the most flexible, in case the task becomes more complex then just "a or not a".

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) is for:

```
import string

table = string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase.replace('a', ''),
                            string.ascii_uppercase.replace('A', ''))

names = ['albert', 'angela', 'leo', 'bridget']

print [name.translate(table) for name in names]
```

`translate` takes a 256 character table, so you use [`string.maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) to turn the [string constants](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-constants) representing the lowercase and uppercase alphabet into a table. Any letters not appearing in the table are ignored, so removing `a` and `A` will uppercase all other letters.

Then just apply the translation table to each name in the list.

It will be faster than iterating over each name and calling `upper` on every letter but `a`. While the general Python tools make this easy, this is the tool specifically made for this job.

Comment: Smart but will not work for letters like `áéüâõ` (if that is needed).

Comment: Just out of curiocity, is it OK to change `string.ascii_*` constants?

Comment: @RonakG Strings are immutable, you can't change them. All `replace` does is return a new string with substrings replaced.

Comment: @agf it will if the locale is set properly

Comment: @agf the gibberish is the uppercased versions which your terminal does not display properly

Comment: @EugeneHomyakov @JBernardo `u'áéüâõ'.upper()` does work for me with `#coding: latin-1` or `#coding: utf-8`, though `'áéüâõ'.upper()` doesn't. Still, this is clearly a homework assignment or tutorial exercise, and all the examples are ASCII, so it's probably not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The inelegant way is simple

```
  lst = ['albert', 'angela', 'leo', 'bridget']
  lst2 = []

  for wrd in lst:
      newwrd = ''
      for ltr in wrd:
          if ltr != 'a':
              newwrd += ltr.upper()
          else: newwrd += ltr
      lst2.append(newwrd)
```

However list complrehensions will be more pythonic

```
lst = ['albert', 'angela', 'leo', 'bridget']
[''.join(ltr.upper() if ltr != 'a' else 'a' for ltr in wrd) for wrd in lst]
```

This is essentially nested list comprehensions replacing the nested loops.
This is a much neater solution and more understandable

A list comprehension is an expression (ltr.upper() if ltr == 'a') followed by  "for" and then option if clauses.  Here we have two (and I see  @JBernardo did the same thing) acting in same way as nested for loops.

I hope that helps explain the differences.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to engage the functional programming paradigm a bit more:

```
def maybe_upper(c, u):
    return c.upper() if c in u else c

def some_upper(s, u):
    return ''.join(map(lambda c: maybe_upper(c, u), s))

>>> some_upper("wahwahweeeewagh", 'uea')
'wAhwAhwEEEEwAgh'
```