# In python, how do you not change the case of every letter in a list element?

Tags: python, list, uppercase, lowercase

I have a list of names:

```
name_list = ['brad', 'james', 'joe', 'alex']
```

and need to change all the letters to upper case except for the a's, such that I would have:

```
name_list = ['BRaD', 'JaMES', 'JOE', 'aLEX']
```

I know how to change all the letters to uppercase:

```
for name in range(0, len(name_list), 1:
  name_list[name] = name_list[name].upper
```

But I'm lost as to how to not change the case of the 'a'.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate python list and capitalize specific letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648878/iterate-python-list-and-capitalize-specific-letters)

Comment: Looks like your professor assigns the same homeworks year after year...

Answer (score 13):

Convert to uppercase, then change "A"s to "a"s

```
[name.upper().replace("A", "a") for name in name_list]
```

Comment: Ahh, I was thinking something like that, but the ways I was trying weren't working.  Thanks!

Comment: This one is way more efficient than mine, and simpler than the other str.translate() solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
import string

table = string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase,
                         string.ascii_uppercase.replace('A', 'a'))

>>> [name.translate(table) for name in name_list]
['BRaD', 'JaMES', 'JOE', 'aLEX']
```

Or an alternate solution using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'[^a]+')
>>> repl = lambda m: m.group(0).upper()
>>> [regex.sub(repl, name) for name in name_list]
['BRaD', 'JaMES', 'JOE', 'aLEX']
```

Comment: That regex version is magnitudes slower than your first one. I would stick with your first

Comment: @jdi - Good to know, I didn't take the time to do timing comparisons.

Comment: You get about a 35% increase if you precompile the regex first: `rx = re.compile(r'[^a]+')`

Answer (score 0):

```
name_list = [''.join(l.upper() if l!='a' else l for l in word) for word in name_list]
```

Comment: Gah. I apologize for posting this after I realized its homework :-/